# find the correct option

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

If f(x) is continuous and differentiable function such that f(1/n)=0 for all n€N, then {OPTIONS}
a.)) f(x)=0 for all x€ N U (0,1]
b.)) f(0)=0 , f'(0)=0
c.)) f'(0)=0 , f"(0)=0
d.)) f(0) and f'(0) may or may not be zero.
Answer is option b.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of continuity of $f(x)$:
$$
0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} f(1/n) = f(\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} 1/n) = f(0)
$$

Comment: i get it but your answer is only a part of question i asked. can u give me a full solution. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since differentiable:

f'(0)=

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {f(1/n) -f(0)}{1/n} =$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nf(1/n) = 0, $

since $f(1/n) = 0$ for $ n \in \mathbb{N}.$